# Which is better option for experienced .NET developer - SharePoint or Dynamics CRM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, dynamics-crm

I am thinking of learning new technology. I have 8+ years of experience in .NET and now am planning to move to new technology. I was involved in couple of SharePoint projects. Before I start learning, I would like to know the following points.

1. Current SharePoint market
2. Salaries compared with .NET
3. Any idea whether Dynamics CRM would be better interms of career and salary over SharePoint.

Edit

I am also open to learn non-MS technologies. I think it is broader question to ask. What I am looking for is emerging technologies which has good career options. Machine Learning and AI is not a choice for me as I am bad with Calculas and Statistics. I am ok with Discrete Maths and Algorithms. Would be wise to learn a enterprise tool or pick any other latest language such as Go?

Comment: On a global scale both SharePoint and Dynamics are 10 to 20 year old technologies. So learning either of those from scratch is like starting to learn Cobol. Have you considered SPFx? That is a modern technology stack

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, I have worked with MOSS 2007 and SharePoint online building webparts, add-ins, etc. It is not a scratch but Dynamics CRM is. I haven't heard of SPFx, thanks for the guidance. May I know how is the market for SharePoint (Online/SPFx). I am also wondering whether to stick with MS stack or go for any other tools?

Comment: The MS Stack is shifting to the Front-End, that is what SPFx (SharePoint Framework) is all about. Personally I value experienced WebDevelopers venturing into the MS market over .Net developers now having to learn the Front-End stack. Techie intro into SPFx: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/followup-to-my-building-client-side-web-parts-with-the-sharepoint-framework-rencore-webinar

Comment: Yes, I agree. There is deep learning curve for .NET developer to become a front end developer. We used bootstrap, knockout in our projects but not extensively. Before putting the efforts on much evolving front-end stack, I thought I would seek advise on tools or other technologies which I am not aware of.

Comment: I have read in other article somewhere that soon or later .NET and Java will decline. As companies will focus more towards business tools, automation and cloud rather than applications.

Comment: Microsoft developed TypeScript to ease .Net heads into the future. Just understand it is still ES6 (JavaScript) you are developing, so unless you want to look like an idiot and do ES3 code patterns in TypeScript (like some MVPs now do) be sure to learn ES6. If you have an aversion to JavaScript.. good luck.. NodeJS, Gulp, the whole toolchain is JavaScript now